# AttributeError: 'inspect module' object has no attribute 'signature' for python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, flask-caching

In my application till now I have been using `flask-caching 1.0` but now I have to upgrade it to `version 1.8` to use the newly intriduced changes but with python 2.7 its giving attribute error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signature'` and I can see that in python 2.7 version `inspect` module has no attribute signature available.

**Stack trace**

```
ERROR:flask_caching:Exception possibly due to cache backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user_profile/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py", line 795, in decorated_function
    f, *args, **kwargs
  File "/Users/user_profile/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py", line 592, in make_cache_key
    f, args=args, timeout=_timeout, forced_update=forced_update
  File "/Users/user_profile/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py", line 529, in _memoize_version
    fname, instance_fname = function_namespace(f, args=args)
  File "/Users/user_profile/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py", line 80, in function_namespace
    m_args = get_arg_names(f)
  File "/Users/user_profile/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py", line 59, in get_arg_names
    sig = inspect.signature(f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signature'
```

Any suggestion to fix the problem.

Comment: Check the docs for the successor of `signature` attribute. It should be there and if it isn't then you will have to downgrade your module version back to 1.0

Comment: No I don't see any successor for `signature`. I will have to keep using the older package.